# jquery cycleimages - unable to link images

Tags: jquery

i got stuck in a jquery / cycleimages problem. the image slide show works properly, but i'd like to link the pictures with an individual web link which doesnt work. i just added a href in front of the img tag but its still not clickable. any suggestions how to solve this issue?

here we go:

```
< div id="cyclewrap">

< div id="cycleimages">



< a href="my target link 1">< img width="1000" height="360" alt="my text" src="image1.jpg" border="0">< /a>

<a href="my target link 2"><img width="1000" height="360" alt="my text" src="image2.jpg" border="0"></a>


< /div>


< a class="cycleprev" href="#">& nbsp;< /a><br> 
< a class="cyclenext" href="#">& nbsp;< /a>


< div id="caption"><br><br>

< /div>

< div id="cyclewrapnav">& nbsp;< /div><br><br>

< /div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if (jQuery('#cycleimages').length > 0) {
            jQuery('#cycleimages').cycle({ 
                fx: 'scrollHorz',
                speed: 1000,
                timeout: 4000, 
    before: addTitle,
                randomizeEffects: true, 
                easing: 'easeOutCubic',
                next:   '.cyclenext', 
                prev:   '.cycleprev',
                pager:  '#cyclewrapnav',
                cleartypeNoBg: true

            });
        }
    });
```

function addTitle() {
        $('#caption').text(this.alt);
    };

```
</script>
```

best wishes,
steve

Answer (score 0):

got it by myself.

```
function addTitle() { 
    var alt = $('img', this).attr('alt');
    $('#caption').html(alt); 
}
```

this solves the whole issue.
thank you anyway!

best
steve